# What information can be returned to the DotNetNuke ModuleSearchBase via an API Controller?

Tags: search, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-9

We currently have the following code on our custom DNN module:

```
 public class FeatureController : ModuleSearchBase
    {

        public CommonDataDefinitions.Products.WebProductDetails ProductDetails { get; set; } = null;


        public override IList<SearchDocument> GetModifiedSearchDocuments(ModuleInfo moduleInfo, DateTime beginDateUtc)
        {

            var searchDocuments = new List<SearchDocument>
            {
                WHAT CAN I RETURN HERE?
            };

            return searchDocuments;

            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Our Detailed Product View module retrieves the following information depending on the SKU in a query string on load using a web API Controller.

- Product.Title
- Product.Description
- Product.Image
- Product.Price
- Product.DetailedDescription
- Product.StockCode Product.MetaTitle
- Product.MetaKeywords
- Product.MetaDescription

The SearchModulebase code will be in the FeatureController class.
This page will be loaded each time someone looks at a product in detail when they navigate from the Product Filter Module.

**1. Since the module will be loaded each time when someone clicks on a particular product. How do you run this code only once and return all the products from the API Controller? Do we need to create an Object which will retrieve everything?**

**2. How do you prevent the module from becoming slow when all the products have to be retrieved on the on load event?**

**3. Which SearchDocument information can be returned for the DNN Crawler to index?**

**4. When the DNN Crawler reads the Feature Controller code, how do you initialize your API Controller to go and fetch and Populate the results to be indexed?**

Comment: There is a lot here in the question which makes it hard for me to answer.  If you are a DNNHero subscriber, check out my tutorial on DNN search integration which includes a working sample module. https://www.dnnhero.com/Premium/Tutorial/ArticleID/305/Search-Integration-DNN-Search-Overview-Part-1-4